# sqlalchemy listening to Database changes

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

is it possible to listen for changes to SqlServer from SQL Alchemy?

ie I have a stored proc execution logging table, tbl_Execution_Log :

```
procedure | Start_Time | End_Time | Status
Proc_1    |  10:15:00  | 10:15:30 | Complete
Proc_2    |  10:15:45  |    -     | Running
```

I want to detect when Proc_2 status changes to complete.

Thanks